# Not creating elements when using if / else in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

---

Hi,

I'm using if / else conditions to create elements in a dictionnary, such as

```
x = {
  'id' : id,
  'image' : res['image'] if 'image' in res.keys() else '',
}
```

Is there a way to not create a image key in the second case ? I cannot remove the else clause, but would like to keep that way of creating the dictionary rather than doing

```
if 'image' in res.keys():
  x['image'] = image
```

Thanks

Comment: Use `'image' in res`, not `'image' in res.keys()`. Same functionality but shorter and faster.

Comment: Also, `res['image'] if 'image' in res else ''` would be better written as `res.get('image', '')`.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't provide the syntactic sugar to do what you want, but  you can slightly change the if statement to fit on one line

```
if 'image' in res.keys(): x['image'] = image
```

Comment: Thanks - but having that if outside the definition is what I'd like to avoid

Comment: Yeah, so the short answer to your question is "No, there isn't a way to have the if within the definition" :P

Comment: PEP 8 doesn't like you doing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a key for a dictioanry, you have to set a value to that so,if you define **'image'** you have to set a value for it...

Some other opti,on is:

```
if 'image' in res.keys():
    x.update({'image':image})
```

but you can not use anything to define a **key-value** pair or not while defining the dictionary...

Comment: Hi - thanks for the info re. the inability to define the pair or not when creating the dictionary ! I guess I'll use your method or the previous one in that case.